# Maven launch of Quarkus tests causes 401 unauthorized error when bootstrap attempts to get dependencies from Nexus repo

Tags: maven, quarkus, nexus

I've just set-up a Jenkins pipeline to test a small Quarkus app. My Jenkins runs in a corporate Kubernetes-based CI/CD environment with corporate Nexus repositories.
The first stage just tries to launch @QuarkusTests (that work locally in my IDE) with:

```
mvn clean test -Dquarkus.test.profile=xxx
```

everything seems to build OK, but when the surefire plugin launches the QuarkusTests, the Quarkus bootstrap tries to get dependencies from the Nexus repo and fails with an HTTP 401 error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:pom:2.15.0.Final from/to shp.mirror (http://<***************>/): authentication failed for http://<***************>/io/quarkus/quarkus-bom/2.15.0.Final/quarkus-bom-2.15.0.Final.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Dependencies were collected correctly from Nexus by Maven with no problems up until this stage.

I checked that the Jenkins user was able to reach the dependeny that failed.

Things that I tried:

- in the surefire maven config, I tried passing the maven config settings from the Jenkins environment, as recommended in the doc (values collected by running mvn -X)

```
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home> 
            <maven.repo.local>${settings.localRepository}</maven.repo.local> 
            <maven.settings>${session.request.userSettingsFile.path}</maven.settings> 
            <maven.top-level-basedir>${session.topLevelProject.basedir.absolutePath}</maven.top-level-basedir> 
            <quarkus.bootstrap.effective-model-builder>true</quarkus.bootstrap.effective-model-builder> 
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
```

- I also tried creating a link between the default settings location (~/.m2/settings.xml and the one used in the Jenkins environment)
- I also tried mvn quarkus:go-offline before running the tests, hoping that this would collect everything needed by the Quarkus bootstrap, but it doesn't seems to make any difference

Any ideas on what may be causing this error, or on how to collect all the dependencies needed by Quarkus bootstrap would be geatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `java.net.ssl.*` properties set in `MAVEN_OPTS` as documented in https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html?
If so, they will also need to be propagated to the surefire plugin.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your reply. The answer is no, but not sure that it matters because the connection seems to be in http (so log extract with the401)

Comment: Is the Maven process before the tests downloading the `quarkus-bom` from the same repo (id and url)?

Comment: ah finally got it! We use password encryption, so need to create a link on settings-security.xml under ~/.m2.
Thanks for your replies

Comment: You should be able to set its location using `settings.security` system property for the surefire plugin and Maven itself.

Comment: yes will try something like that - definitely better, the link was the initial (slightly messy) workaround. cheers

Comment: been having a bit of trouble with this. <maven.settings>${session.request.userSettingsFile.path}</maven.settings> 
refers to a Maven property I suppose (found lots of examples but no reference on this topic) For <settings.security> I can get it working if I specify the property value in the pom properties, but what I would really like is a Maven system property with the path of the settings-security file from the execution context. I found a post that mentioned <settings.security>${<settings.security>}</settings.security> but this doesn't work for me. Is there a Maven property with this value